# Are there ways to determine whether or not a fuse will blow if placed into a circuit?

Tags: fuses

Industrial fuses are quite expensive when compared to the typical fuses found inside your automobile. While trying to locate a fault in a piece of industrial equipment, quite a few fuses were blown trying to use a trial and error method. Is there a way to test the account of current that will flow through a circuit without harming the equipment? Is there a way to tell whether or not a fuse will blow if placed into a circuit? At $30.00 dollars a fuse, I'd like to find a way to test whether or not the fault has been corrected, or if I will still blow another fuse if placed inline. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of fuse?  What kind of equipment?  What voltage and power are you talking about?

Comment: Monitor the current at every point with a clamp meter and a min/max function?

Answer (score 2):

You could temporarily wire-in an equally rated circuit breaker in place of the fuse.

Comment: Yup, take one of the blown fuses and solder a couple of wires to the ends and attach to a breaker.

Comment: Ok so it seems circuit breaker is the answer! Originally I was thinking I could measure the current through the circuit by going inline with a multimeter where the fuse is, then realized any current being measured would be acting on the circuit- e.g. 100 amps on the meter would be 100 amps on a circuit made to handle say... 10. And poof! Magic smoke. Thanks everyone. Btw, it's a 480v cutting machine for those who are curious.